# Why does the Perl conditonal operator behave different with a undefined hashref key?

Tags: perl

Why does the ternary conditional operator behave different with a undefined hashref key than a regular undefined $ variable ?
For example if $form is undefined and $str is defined the following ternary always assigns the value of str to the value of form:
($str) ? $form = $str : $form = $form;
However if undefined hash keys are substituted it no longer works.

I have made a script that demonstrates the odd behavior.
Note you'll get the 'Use of uninitialized value' warnings in all tests.
That is intentional as I am testing for an undefined value.
Thanks in advance

```
    #!/usr/bin/env perl
    # ternary operator
    # condition ? if True : if False 
    # Why does the ternary operator behave different with a undefined hashref key
    # than a regular undefined $ variable ?
    
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

my $i = 1;
my $form = { vc => 'customer', customer_id => ''};
my $ref = { customer_id => 12345 };

&string_test;# passes
print "-" x 80;
&mixed_test_ref; # passes
print "-" x 80;
&mixed_test; #fails
print "-" x 80;
&hashref_test; #fails
print "-" x 80;
&works_always; 
print "-" x 80;
print "\n";

sub string_test {
    my $str = '1234';
    my $form; # not defined
    print qq|
Why does the ternary operator behave different
with a undefined hashref key
than a regular undefined \$ variable ?
First with a undefined variable called form:   
   Before:
        str : '$str' \n
        form : $form
    |; # will throw undefined warning


    # ternary operator
    #condition ? if True : if False  
    ($str) ? $form = $str : 
    $form = $form;

    print qq|
       Always works:
        str : '$str' \n
        form: $form \n|;

}


sub mixed_test_ref {

    my $local;
    print qq|
    Mixed test ref
    Before:
        form->{vc} '$form->{vc}' \n
        ref->{"$form->{vc}_id"} : '$ref->{"$form->{vc}_id"}' \n
    |;


    # ternary operator
    #condition ? if True : if False  
    ($ref->{"$form->{vc}_id"}) ? $local = $ref->{"$form->{vc}_id"} : 
    $local = $local;

    print qq|
        After:
        form->{vc} '$form->{vc}' \n
        ref->{"$form->{vc}_id"} : '$ref->{"$form->{vc}_id"}' \n
         local: '$local' \n
    |;

    if ($local = $ref->{"$form->{vc}_id"}) {print "Pass\n"}
    else {print "Fail\n"}
}

sub mixed_test {
    # $form->{"$form->{vc}_id_$i"} is not defined
    # setting it to empty string makes it pass
    #$form->{"$form->{vc}_id_$i"} = '';
    delete $form->{"$form->{vc}_id_$i"};
    my $str = '1234';
    
    print qq|
    mixed test
    Before:
        str : '$str' \n
        form: '$form->{"$form->{vc}_id_$i"}' \n
    |;


    # ternary operator
    #condition ? if True : if False  
    ($str) ? $form->{"$form->{vc}_id_$i"} = $str : 
    $form->{"$form->{vc}_id_$i"} = $form->{"$form->{vc}_id_$i"};



    if ( $form->{"$form->{vc}_id_$i"} == $str ) {
    print qq|Pass\
        After:
        str : '$str' \n
        form: $form->{"$form->{vc}_id_$i"} \n|;
    }
    else {print "Fail\n"}

}

sub hashref_test {
    # $form->{"$form->{vc}_id_$i"} is not defined
    # setting it to empty string makes it pass
    #$form->{"$form->{vc}_id_$i"} = '';
    delete $form->{"$form->{vc}_id_$i"};
    print qq|
    hash ref test
        Before:
        form->{vc} '$form->{vc}' \n
        ref->{"$form->{vc}_id"} : '$ref->{"$form->{vc}_id"}' \n
        form->{"$form->{vc}_id_$i"} : $form->{"$form->{vc}_id_$i"} \n
    |;


    # ternary operator
    #condition               ? if True : if False  
    $ref->{"$form->{vc}_id"} ? $form->{"$form->{vc}_id_$i"} = $ref->{"$form->{vc}_id"} : 
    $form->{"$form->{vc}_id_$i"} = $form->{"$form->{vc}_id_$i"};

    if ($form->{"$form->{vc}_id_$i"}) {print "Passes and I am amazed\n"}
    else {
        print qq|
            Why does this not work?
            After:
            form->{vc} '$form->{vc}' \n
            ref->{"$form->{vc}_id"} : '$ref->{"$form->{vc}_id"}' \n
            form->{"$form->{vc}_id_$i"} : $form->{"$form->{vc}_id_$i"} \n|;
    }

}

sub works_always {
    if ($ref->{"$form->{vc}_id"}) { $form->{"$form->{vc}_id_$i"} = $ref->{"$form->{vc}_id"} }
    # not necessary but for completeness
    else { $form->{"$form->{vc}_id_$i"} = $form->{"$form->{vc}_id_$i" } }

    print qq|
        Always works as expected with if statement:
        form->{vc} '$form->{vc}' \n
        ref->{"$form->{vc}_id"} : '$ref->{"$form->{vc}_id"}' \n
        form->{"$form->{vc}_id_$i"} : $form->{"$form->{vc}_id_$i"} \n|;
}
```

Comment: It's called the conditional operator. It's merely a ternary operator.

Comment: Do you really need all this code to demonstrate your problem? You should cut 95% of this code away.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I knew when I saw the title of the question that the answer would be about precedence.

You might think that

```
($str) ? $form = $str : $form = $form;
```

means

```
if ($str) {
    $form = $str;
} else {
    $form = $form;
}
```

But this command

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse,-p -e '($str) ? $form = $str : $form = $form'
(($str ? ($form = $str) : $form) = $form);
```

shows us that it really means

```
if ($str) {
    $form = $str = $form;
} else {
    $form = $form;
}
```

This can be fixed in many ways. With more parentheses:

```
($str) ? ($form = $str) : ($form = $form)
```

or by writing a much simpler expression:

```
$form = $str if $str;
$form = $str || $form;
```

Comment: To be clear, use either `$form = $str if $str;` or `$form = $str || $form;`, not both.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, i'll be using -MO=Deparse more often thats new to me.